# firebase storage bucket gives 403 for non authentication required files if files are uploaded via firebase web interface

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-storage, django-storage

I have uploaded some static files to the bucket via the web interface of firebase. Here are my security rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{static=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth == null
    }
  }
}
```

If I upload the files via the django admin (using django-storages) I can access the files that are in the static folder without authentication. If I use the firebase webinterface to upload them, I receive a 403. What additional security rule am I missing here?

// Edit - I have figured out that

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-project-name.appspot.com/static/entries/file.jpg
```

does not work, while

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project-name.appspot.com/o/static/file.jpg?alt=media
```

works. I may have used the wrong public bucket URL.